# Getting Error while click on Launch the Appium Node server button

Tags: android, ios, appium

I just click on Launch the Appium Node server button then I will get this type of error message and process will be turn off withing a second within this error.

Any help will be most appreciated!

> ```
>            usage: main.js [-h] [-v] [--shell]
>            [--localizable-strings-dir LOCALIZABLESTRINGSDIR] [--app APP]
>            [--ipa IPA] [-U UDID] [-a ADDRESS] [-p PORT]
>            main.js: error: argument "--app": Expected one argument. null
>            [-ca CALLBACKADDRESS] [-cp CALLBACKPORT] [-bp BOOTSTRAPPORT]
>            [-k] [-r BACKENDRETRIES] [--session-override] [--full-reset]
>            [--no-reset] [-l] [-lt LAUNCHTIMEOUT] [-g LOG]
>            [--log-level {info,info:debug,info:info,info:warn,info:error,warn,warn:debug,warn:info,warn:warn,warn:error,error,error:debug,error:info,error:warn,error:error,debug,debug:debug,debug:info,debug:warn,debug:error}]
>            [--log-timestamp] [--local-timezone] [--log-no-colors]
>            [-G WEBHOOK] [--native-instruments-lib]
>            [--app-pkg ANDROIDPACKAGE] [--app-activity ANDROIDACTIVITY]
>            [--app-wait-package ANDROIDWAITPACKAGE]
>            [--app-wait-activity ANDROIDWAITACTIVITY]
>            [--android-coverage ANDROIDCOVERAGE] [--avd AVD]
>
>            [--avd-args AVDARGS]
>            [--device-ready-timeout ANDROIDDEVICEREADYTIMEOUT] [--safari]
>            [--device-name DEVICENAME] [--platform-name PLATFORMNAME]
>            [--platform-version PLATFORMVERSION]
>            [--automation-name AUTOMATIONNAME] [--browser-name BROWSERNAME]
>            [--default-device] [--force-iphone] [--force-ipad]
>            [--language LANGUAGE] [--locale LOCALE]
>            [--calendar-format CALENDARFORMAT] [--orientation ORIENTATION]
>            [--tracetemplate AUTOMATIONTRACETEMPLATEPATH]
>            [--instruments INSTRUMENTSPATH] [--show-sim-log]
>            [--show-ios-log] [--nodeconfig NODECONFIG] [-ra ROBOTADDRESS]
>            [-rp ROBOTPORT] [--selendroid-port SELENDROIDPORT]
>            [--chromedriver-port CHROMEDRIVERPORT]
>            [--chromedriver-executable CHROMEDRIVEREXECUTABLE]
>            [--use-keystore] [--keystore-path KEYSTOREPATH]
>            [--keystore-password KEYSTOREPASSWORD] [--key-alias KEYALIAS]
>            [--key-password KEYPASSWORD] [--show-config] [--no-perms-check]
>            [--command-timeout DEFAULTCOMMANDTIMEOUT] [--keep-keychains]
>            [--strict-caps] [--isolate-sim-device] [--tmp TMPDIR]
>            [--trace-dir TRACEDIR] [--intent-action INTENTACTION]
>            [--intent-category INTENTCATEGORY] [--intent-flags INTENTFLAGS]
>            [--intent-args OPTIONALINTENTARGUMENTS]
>            [--dont-stop-app-on-reset] [--debug-log-spacing]
>            [--suppress-adb-kill-server] [--async-trace]
> ```

Comment: what is it that you are trying to do? and could you share the entire logs

Comment: Please share the capabilities that you used..Or share screenshot of options that you used before launching the server